# How to prevent scrolling up when clicking an anchor link to show hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, anchor

Does somebody could help me please? I already tried a lot of scripts and nothing have worked yet.
If you go to this url [https://www.yessbrasil.com/Ty67UwaBn932ml10DpgE54QvkG8Jd/boleiras_doceiras.html](https://www.yessbrasil.com/Ty67UwaBn932ml10DpgE54QvkG8Jd/boleiras_doceiras.html/) and click in any name of the list **from 1 to 43**, the div jumps up and scrolls all the page up until the hidden div appears.

I saved this script below as a **jquery.jump.js** inside the **js** folder.

```
$("a:link").on("click", function(e){
    if($(this).attr("href").match("^#")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //some other stuff you want to do with the hash, like smooth scroll to anchor
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

*Thank you in advance and I apologize for any errors due to amateur skills.*